# Loading Wordpress metakeys with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

at the moment my theme I load posts with AJAX. But how can I can get also post meta keys via AJAX?

At the moment functions PHP is like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_loading');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_action', 'ajax_loading');

function ajax_loading() {
    switch($_REQUEST['fn']) {
        case 'get_latest_posts':
        $output = ajax_get_latest_posts($_REQUEST['count']);
        break;
        default:
        $output = 'Error. No function specified.';
        break;
    }
    $output = json_encode($output);
    if (is_array($output)) {
        print_r($output);
    }
    else {
        echo $output;
    }
    die;
}

function ajax_get_latest_posts($count) {
     $posts = get_posts('numberposts='.$count.'&post_status=publish');

     return $posts;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action': 'ajax_action',
            'fn': 'get_latest_posts',
            'count': 15
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data){
            //print stuff here
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            //error stuff here
        }
    })
```

With these code i only get the main post info (title, id, date, content...).

So have anyone tried to get meta keys/values with AJAX/JS from posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your `ajax_get_latest_posts()` function to something like this:

```
function ajax_get_latest_posts($count) {
  $posts = get_posts('numberposts='.$count.'&post_status=publish');

  foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
    $posts[$key]->meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
  }

  return $posts;
}
```

I've added a 'meta' key to each `posts` using [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Hmm, it gives error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array. It's for this line: $posts[$key]['meta'] = get_post_meta($post->ID);

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Wordpress env to check it on. it should probably be `$posts[$key]->meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);` since $posts is an Array of WP objects and not arrays

Comment: Indeed, I should have thought that myself. Got it working. Thanks a lot!